# How to add a dummy variable as a new column in a pre-existing dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm using R, and I'm not sure how to create a dummy variable for existing data.

The data has the names of several countries, and I want to add a dummy variable that is equal to `1` for certain countries and equal to `0` depending on certain criteria; i.e. `dummy == 1` if country is type A, `dummy == 0` if country is type B. How do I set this up, and then how do I add that dummy variable as a new column in the dataset?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try something like that `df$dummy = ifelse(df$country == "A",1,0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two types, e.g. type `A` and `B`, the answer provided in comments with `ifelse()` is workable.

However, if there are more than two types, one will need more than one column to store the varying levels of `type` as dummy variables. The `dummies` package can be used for this purpose. If `type` is a column in a data frame, we can use the `dummies::dummy()` function to create one dummy variable for each type. We'll illustrate with some sample data.

```
 textFile <- "name,country,type
Joe,England,A
Herve,France,A
Pat,US,B
Jane,US,B
Frank,Canada,B,
Julio,Mexico,C
Juan,Cuba,C"

data <- read.csv(text=textFile)
dummyData <- dummy(data$type)
dummyData
```

...and the output:

```
> dummyData
     typeA typeB typeC
[1,]     1     0     0
[2,]     1     0     0
[3,]     0     1     0
[4,]     0     1     0
[5,]     0     1     0
[6,]     0     0     1
[7,]     0     0     1
>
```

To add the dummy data to the input data frame, we use the `dummy.data.frame()` function.

```
dummyData <- dummy.data.frame(names = c("type"),data = data)
dummyData
```

...and the output:

```
> dummyData
   name country typeA typeB typeC
1   Joe England     1     0     0
2 Herve  France     1     0     0
3   Pat      US     0     1     0
4  Jane      US     0     1     0
5 Frank  Canada     0     1     0
6 Julio  Mexico     0     0     1
7  Juan    Cuba     0     0     1
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the data doesn't come with a "type" column -- I need to first assign each type to each country by using the country's name somehow. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: @RK124 There are a number of ways to do this, but you'll need to explain what "type" is (including how types relate to countries) and provide some sample data for us to help you.On Stackoverlow, you get more relevant answers when your questions are [Minimal and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My answer is a good example of this technique because I provide sample data that makes it obvious how I addressed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use data.table to chain it, first giving all rows a 0, then 1s in your chosen rows

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(
  "V1" = c("a", "a", "b"),
  "V2" = c("b", "c", "c"),
  "V3" = c(2,6,9)) 

DT1[, dummy := 0][V1 == "a", dummy := 1]
```

Seeing your comment on another answer, you dont have a "type" column, which is V1 here. If you have vector of countries that are of each type ("typeVector") then use `%in%`

```
# if you need to manually make the vector first...
typeVector <- c("US", "Finland", "Germany")
# assign a 1 to those selected countries...
DT1[, dummy := 0][country %in% typeVector, dummy := 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ifelse` clause.

**DATA**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Liberia","Sudan", "Reunion", "Ghana", 
              "Bangladesh", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Syria", "Latvia"))
```

**SOLUTION**:

Let's say one condition for a country to obtain the value `1`is that its name starts with uppercase `S`. You can define that as a pattern to match with `grepl` and when `ifelse` evaluates to TRUE assign the value `1`; else you assign the value `0`:

```
df$dummy <- ifelse(grepl("^S", df$Country), 1, 0)
```

**RESULT**:

```
df
     Country dummy
1    Liberia     0
2      Sudan     1
3    Reunion     0
4      Ghana     0
5 Bangladesh     0
6 San Marino     1
7     Serbia     1
8      Syria     1
9     Latvia     0
```